# Controller instance variable not renders at JS view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have controller:

```
class CommentariesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_commentary, only: [:update, :destroy]
  before_action :find_commentable, only: [:create]

  def create
    @commentary = @commentable.commentaries.new(commentary_params)
    @commentary.user_id = current_user.id
    @commentary.save!
  end

  def update
    @commentary.update(commentary_params) if current_user.authorized_for?(@commentary)
  end

  def destroy
    @commentary.destroy  if current_user.authorized_for?(@commentary)
  end

  private

  def find_commentary
    @commentary = Commentary.find(params[:id])
  end

  def commentary_params
    params.require(:commentary).permit(:body)
  end

  def find_commentable
    if params[:question_id]
      @commentable = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    elsif params[:answer_id]
      @commentable = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    end
  end
end
```

And view for it's `create` action:

```
("#<% @commentary.commentable_type.underscore %>-<% @commentary.id %>").append("<% j render @commentary %>")
```

`_commentary.html.slim`:

```
div class='d-flex justify-content-end mb-2'
  div class='card col-10'
    div class='card-body small text-muted' = commentary.body
```

When `create` action is being processed, all is right, commentaries are being created, and saved to the DB successfully, but instead of jQuery adds a commentary html code rendered, I get no errors, but such response:

```
$("#-").append("")
```

I can't realize what happens here, so that I get no errors, commentaries are saved, but I get empty commentary object fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `<% %>` and `<%= %>` in ERB, first one doesnt output anything, the second one does.

```
$("#<% @commentary.commentable_type.underscore %>-<% @commentary.id %>")
```

Shoud be:

```
$("#<%= @commentary.commentable_type.underscore %>-<%= @commentary.id %>")
```